# Html hover tooltip is displaying below other layers. How to move it to the top?

Tags: html, css, hover, tooltip

I am displaying a table and want to show some notes above some table labels. Tried to maximize z-index of hovered element, but did not work. Stil the tooltip is showing below the th elements.

Is there a way to show the tooltip above all other layers?

I put smaller version of table into a code snippet. Problematic part is already at the beginning in the second  cell, with number 2021. I made the tooltip really long to show that it is actually displaying but for some reason it is behind the background.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```css
table,
td,
th {
  font-family: trial;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff font-size: 11px;
}

th {
  left: 0;
  font-family: trial-bold;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #e72076;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff
}

table {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #fff
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #20323f;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #20323f;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e72076;
}

td:nth-last-child(5n+1) {
  border-right: 1px solid #e72076;
}

th:nth-child(6n+1) {
  border-right: 0px solid #fff
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: trial;
}

th.tip {
  text-decoration: none z-index: 2;
}

th.tip:hover {
  position: relative
}

th.tip span {
  display: none
}

th.tip:hover span {
  width: 170px;
  border: #fff 1px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2147483647;
  background: #20323f;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

td.right_border {
  border-right: 1px solid #e72076;
}

td.tip {
  text-decoration: none
}

td.tip:hover {
  position: relative
}

td.tip span {
  display: none
}

td.tip:hover span {
  width: 170px;
  border: #fff 1px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #20323f;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="tip" colspan="5" halign="left">2021<span>........ ............................................. .................................2021-01-21-2021-02-05</span></th>
      <th class="tip" colspan="5" halign="left">2020<span>........ ............................................. .................................2020-04-01-2020-06-30</span></th>
      <th colspan="5" halign="left" style="border-right: 0px solid #ccc">2019</th>
      <th colspan="5" halign="left" style="border-right: 0px solid #ccc">2018</th>
      <th colspan="5" halign="left" style="border-right: 0px solid #ccc">2017</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>total</th>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="tip">2 (2 / 0 / 0)<span>hired total (juniors / mids / seniors)</span></td>
      <td class="tip">526 (18 - 43 - 67)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="tip">1 (1 / 0 / 0)<span>hired total</span></td>
      <td class="tip">1000 (10 - 100 - 100)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 / 0 / 0)<span>hired total</span></td>
      <td class="tip">1111 (0 - 0 - 100)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="tip">1 (1 / 0 / 0)<span>hired</span></td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 / 0 / 0)<span>hired</span></td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>LinkedIn</th>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (echo -> interview rate in % - inteview -> success rate in % / success -> hired rate in %)</span></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your html to the question for a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try to add more info next time. I added the code snippet to the question now. Do you have any idea, where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip is show below the hovered cell because you defined for it `top: 2.2em`. But you can define top also to be negative to show the tooltip above the hovered cell.

Since you defined `position: sticky` for every `th` the tooltips for the thead are not big enough for such a big tooltip like for the cell "2021". You could remove the position definition for the `th`s to show the full size tooltip. For the thead to be sticky it is enough to define it only for the first `th`.

```
th:first-child { 
  position: sticky; 
}
```

By the way, there was a mistake in your CSS:

```
text-decoration: none z-index: 2;
```

These are two separate statements, so the following is correct:

```
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 2;
```

**Working example**:

```css
table,
td,
th {
  font-family: trial;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff font-size: 11px;
}

th {
  left: 0;
  font-family: trial-bold;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #e72076;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff
}

th:first-child { 
  position: sticky; 
} 

table {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #fff
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #20323f;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #20323f;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e72076;
}

td:nth-last-child(5n+1) {
  border-right: 1px solid #e72076;
}

th:nth-child(6n+1) {
  border-right: 0px solid #fff
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: trial;
}

th.tip {
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

th.tip:hover {
  position: relative
}

th.tip span {
  display: none
}

th.tip:hover span {
  width: 170px;
  border: #fff 1px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2147483647;
  background: #20323f;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

td.right_border {
  border-right: 1px solid #e72076;
}

td.tip {
  text-decoration: none
}

td.tip:hover {
  position: relative
}

td.tip span {
  display: none
}

td.tip:hover span {
  width: 170px;
  border: #fff 1px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #20323f;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="tip" colspan="5" halign="left">2021<span>........ ............................................. .................................2021-01-21-2021-02-05</span></th>
      <th class="tip" colspan="5" halign="left">2020<span>........ ............................................. .................................2020-04-01-2020-06-30</span></th>
      <th colspan="5" halign="left" style="border-right: 0px solid #ccc">2019</th>
      <th colspan="5" halign="left" style="border-right: 0px solid #ccc">2018</th>
      <th colspan="5" halign="left" style="border-right: 0px solid #ccc">2017</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
      <th>echo</th>
      <th>interview</th>
      <th>success</th>
      <th>hired</th>
      <th class="tip">funnel<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>total</th>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="tip">2 (2 / 0 / 0)<span>hired total (juniors / mids / seniors)</span></td>
      <td class="tip">526 (18 - 43 - 67)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="tip">1 (1 / 0 / 0)<span>hired total</span></td>
      <td class="tip">1000 (10 - 100 - 100)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 / 0 / 0)<span>hired total</span></td>
      <td class="tip">1111 (0 - 0 - 100)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="tip">1 (1 / 0 / 0)<span>hired</span></td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 / 0 / 0)<span>hired</span></td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>LinkedIn</th>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>hired rate in ‱ (...)</span></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="tip">0 (0 - 0 - 0)<span>echo -> hired rate in ‱ (echo -> interview rate in % - inteview -> success rate in % / success -> hired rate in %)</span></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Problem is that now, tooltip is now shown not above or close by mouse but at the left edge of table. For tooltip for 2021 it is quite ok, but try to move above 2020.

Comment: Where do you want it do appear?

Comment: Somewhere close to that element. It should be sth like a help showing some extra information for that time period.

Comment: Ok, then ```position: relative``` for the cells was correct, just ```top``` had to be changed. I updated my answer...

Comment: Actually the part part of your solution that solves my issue is avoiding position: sticky for the cells.
Small problem is that it was there on purpose - I really want the first the column to be fixed. But I just solution also for this. I should better use:
th:first-child {
     position: sticky
    }
Thank you anyway, consider maybe to add this to your answer.